# Health analyzer rule is important Validate the My Site Host and individual My Sites are on a dedicated Web application and separate URL domain*

Tags: 2010, mysite, health-analyzer

What this health analyzer rule is it important to create a separate web application in a farm to host the My Site host and individual My Sites In every sharepoint farm.
We now have farm for record management and content management.

**Validate the My Site Host and individual My Sites are on a dedicated Web application and separate URL domain**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually MySite Host are supposed to be hosted on a separate Web Application and separate databases. This is best practice according to Microsoft.

However, you don't have to if you have valid reasons not to. In your case where you have a farm used for records management and content management, you should really consider using MySite Host on a web application of its own. Especially if you have a large organisation with hundreds of MySite users.

But if that isn't the case, you can edit the health rule and disable it for the time being. When your done disabling the rule, you can simply delete this instance of the error and it won't show up again.

Comment: Hi We are not using Mysites in our organisation so can i disable this health rule?

Comment: @adilahmed Sure! And if the organisation decides to use MySite, its easy to enable it again!